# How to invoke a rake task from within a test program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not trying to test rake tasks. I have a test program which sends out emails ( real emails yes) to test email templates etc.

```
class EmailTemplatesTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase    
  context 'send_password_info' do
    setup do
      Emailtb.send_password_info(user)
      Rake::Task['email:run'].invoke # this actually delivers email
    end
    should 'have one emailtb' do
      assert_equal 1, Emailtb.count
    end
  end    
end
```

When I run this test then I get following error.

```
RuntimeError: Don't know how to build task 'email:run'
```

However if I run the rake task separately then it works fine

```
  rake email:run
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test environment doesn't load files in lib.  You have to manually load them at the top of the file, like so:

```
require 'rake'
load File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'lib', 'tasks', 'my_task.rake')  
class EmailTemplatesTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase    
  context 'send_password_info' do
    setup do
      Emailtb.send_password_info(user)
      Rake::Task['email:run'].invoke # this actually delivers email
    end
    should 'have one emailtb' do
      assert_equal 1, Emailtb.count
    end
  end    
end
```

Comment: Use Rails.root in Rails 5